# How to set mySql's CURDATE date for tests?

Tags: mysql

How can one easily set the date returned by mySql CURDATE() method to an arbitrary one?

Is it defined by the system clock? Can you send an SQL query to tweak it for testing?

We are setting a test environment for our API. We are building regression tests to make sure all endpoints perform the correct side effect and return the correct response.

However, endpoints that return the number of events for the current week will fail unless we change the CURDATE to match the date the test was written. The desired behaviour is to receive the same result even if a test is run in the future.

Comment: "Is it defined by the system clock?" i pretty sure CURDATE() depens on the OS date and time and MySQL configured timezone which most likely is the default OS timezone.. "Can you send an SQL query to tweak it for testing?" You can use a `SET time_zone = timezone;` query ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html ).. Not sure if this helps you because of that i've made a comment out off it.

Comment: See a example notice the time changes for the last two results.. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gyMh4HJqxD3UNFSEfBvYsJ/1